# Get value of certain index in list C#

Tags: c#, list, collections

I want to get value of a certain index on my list how can do that? I have here a method that returns List of Games:

```
public static List<BO.Game> GetGames()
    {
        List<BO.Game> listGame = new List<BO.Game>();

        BO.Game game;



        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

        try
        {
            con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.CommandText = "GetDisplayPicOfContest";

            SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                game = new BO.Game();
                game.PrizeID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PrizeID"]);
                game.Name = dr["LocationName"].ToString();
                game.ImageURL = "DisplayImages/" + dr["DisplayImage"].ToString();
                game.Country = dr["CountryName"].ToString();
                listGame.Add(game);
            }


            dr.Close();
            dr.Dispose();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally

        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }

        return listGame;
    }
```

For example I want to display the image url of the first and second item on the list

can I do something like this?

```
<div id="mcont2-sub1" class="mcont-subs mcont-subs-2">
                    <div class="full-detais-cover2">

                        <a class="opac-link" href="game_details.html" ><img  class="hover-img-main" src="<%=listGames[0].ImageURL;%>" /></a>

                        <a class="opac-link" href="game_details.html" ><div id="cover-pager2"><img src="Images/lens-full-details.png" /></div></a>
                        <div class="ticket-quantity2">
                        <span>Choose ticket quantity</span><span>Tickets $5.00</span>
                            <ul class="quantity-paging">
                                <li><a>&nbsp;1&nbsp;</a></li>
                                <li><a>&nbsp;2&nbsp;</a></li>
                                <li><a>&nbsp;3&nbsp;</a></li>
                                <li><a>&nbsp;4&nbsp;</a></li>
                                <li><a>&nbsp;5&nbsp;</a></li>
                                <li><a>10</a></li>
                                <li><a>15</a></li>
                                <li><a>20</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="descrip-place" id="id-descrip-place">
                        <p class="description">Marbella Beach Club Marriott</p>
                        <p class="place">Spain</p>
                    </div>
                    <a  href="game_details.html" class="arrow-light-blue" ><img src="Images/arrow-light-blue.png" /></a>
                </div>

                <div id="mcont2-sub2" class="mcont-subs mcont-subs-2">
                    <a href="game_details.html" ><img src="<%=listGames[1].ImageURL;%>" /></a>
                    <div class="descrip-place" id="Div1">
                        <p class="description">Waiohai Beach Club Marriott</p>
                        <p class="place">Hawaii</p>
                    </div>
                    <a  href="game_details.html" class="arrow-light-blue" ><img src="Images/arrow-light-blue.png" /></a>
                </div>
```

Comment: are you following MVC ??

Comment: Have you tried your code?

Comment: @Arun - this is webforms

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - yes i tried already but it's not working

Comment: List<BO.Game> - change it to ToArray() or IEnumarable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly do You need, but if You want to **get value of certain index in list C#** You can just do this using `square brackets syntax`:

```
List<something> list = GetListOfSomething();
var someItem = list[yourIndex];
```

You can do this because `List<T>` implements `IList<T>` interface which defines this indexer:

```
object this[int index] { get; set; }
```

Also You can use `Linq to Objects` to query your List.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to resolve is to replace the following code

```
<img  class="hover-img-main" src="<%=listGames[0].ImageURL;%>" />
```

with an asp.net Image Control and set its src from code-behind.

Comment: I cannot replace it with image control due to design issues.

Comment: What kind of error are you facing.? Replace your code with the following line and see what kind of url is coming in the alt text for testing purpose.                                                 <img  class="hover-img-main" alt="<%=listGames[0].ImageURL;%>" />

Comment: Here's the error:        Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected